# ¿Por qué no puedo traer los datos de manera correcta? (Angular)

Tags: angular

Estoy teniendo problemas para hacer que funcione correctamente una parte de una aplicación que estoy desarrollando:

**Esta es la lógica del componente:**

```
export class EstadoStockComponent implements OnInit{

  articulos: ArticuloInsumo[] = [];
  nivelSeleccionado: any;

  constructor(private service: ArticuloInsumoService) {
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datosBackend();
  }


  datosBackend() {

    this.service.getArticulosInsumos().subscribe(res => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let stockActual = res[i].stockActual;
        let stockMinimo = res[i].stockMinimo;
        if (stockActual < stockMinimo) {
          this.articulos.push(res[i]);
        }
      }
    })
    console.log(this.articulos);
  }

  filtrarPorNiveles(event: any) {

    const nivel = event.target.value;
    this.nivelSeleccionado = nivel;
  }

  seleccionarNivel() {

    console.log("Nivel seleccionado: " + this.nivelSeleccionado);
    if (this.nivelSeleccionado === "todos") {
      this.service.getArticulosInsumos().subscribe(res => {
        this.articulos = res;
      })
    }
    console.log(this.articulos);
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Filtrar por niveles de Stock</label>
        <select (change)="filtrarPorNiveles($event)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="todos">Todos</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="seleccionarNivel()">Seleccionar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Paso a explicar el código:**

Apenas se acceda al componente me debe de mostrar por consola aquellos "artículos" que cumplan con la condición desarrollada, en esta parte creo que no estoy teniendo problemas porque me trae de manera correcta los datos deseados. (ngOnInit)

El problema que estoy teniendo es cuando selecciono alguna de las opciones del listado, por ejemplo el nivel "todos", este me tendría que traer todos los artículos y para que me los traiga debo de hacer click 2 veces. Para clarificar dejo este ejemplo:

**Ejemplo '1':**

1. Entro al componente y gracias al método que se ejecuta en el ngOnInit() me muestra un arreglo vacío porque de momento no hay registros que coincidan con la condición.
2. Selecciono del listado la opción 'todos' e intento traer todos los registros ,pero me trae el mismo resultado que obtuve gracias al ngOnInit. Para lograr lo deseado debo de volver a clickear y que se ejecute nuevamente el método 'seleccionarNivel()'.

Desde ya muchas gracias y agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda!

Comment: Cuando seleccionas `todos` en el listado se ejecuta la función `filtrarPorNiveles()` y dentro solo se guarda el nivel seleccionado. Ahí mismo podrías llamar a la función `seleccionarNivel()` para no tener que hacer clic al botón.